# How does immortality work?

Tags: uq-holder

Can someone explain to me how immortality works in UQ Holder? Specifically about how each type of immortality works and what is required to kill that type?

Comment: Chapter 6 explains the types of immortality that exist, but says nothing about what it takes to kill each type. See pages [14](http://i.imgur.com/YDTm0R4.png), [15](http://i.imgur.com/X6GsitD.png), [16](http://i.imgur.com/PYper5J.png) and [17](http://i.imgur.com/DvVQaN9.png).